# General solution of inscribed square problem

Tags: equation-solving, computational-geometry

There is my earlier  question about [Inscribed square problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116459/inscribed-square-problem)

Now I tried to find the general solution for any curve $f(x,y)=0$.

For instance :

$\qquad \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)^3-x^2 y^3=0$

```
ContourPlot[(-1 + x^2 + y^2)^3 == x^2*y^3, {x, -1.4, 1.4}, {y, -1.3, 1.5},
Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

There are three **general conditions** to find vertices of a square:

Coordinates of vertices are $(p1,k1),(p2,k2),(p3,k3),(p4,k4)$

Let

```
g[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3
```

$1.$ Vertex coordinates satisfy heart equation $g(x,y)=0$

```
eq1 = g[p1, k1] == 0;
eq2 = g[p2, k2] == 0;
eq3 = g[p3, k3] == 0;
eq4 = g[p4, k4] == 0;
```

$2.$ All sides have equal length.

```
eq5 = 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p2, k2}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p2, k2}, {p3, k3}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p3, k3}, {p4, k4}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p4, k4}];
```

$3.$ Every interior angle is a right angle

```
angle1 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p1, k4 - k1}, {p2 - p1, k2 - k1}] == Pi/2;
angle2 = VectorAngle[{p1 - p2, k1 - k2}, {p3 - p2, k3 - k2}] == Pi/2;
angle3 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p3, k4 - k3}, {p2 - p3, k2 - k3}] == Pi/2;


NSolve[eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && angle1 && angle2 && 
angle3, {p1, p2, p3, p4, k1, k2, k3, k4}]
```

But there is no answer.

**How can I solve the following system of equation by using *Mathematica?***

```
g[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3

eq1 = g[p1, k1] == 0;
eq2 = g[p2, k2] == 0;
eq3 = g[p3, k3] == 0;
eq4 = g[p4, k4] == 0;

eq5 = 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p2, k2}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p2, k2}, {p3, k3}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p3, k3}, {p4, k4}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p4, k4}];

angle1 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p1, k4 - k1}, {p2 - p1, k2 - k1}] == Pi/2;
angle2 = VectorAngle[{p1 - p2, k1 - k2}, {p3 - p2, k3 - k2}] == Pi/2;
angle3 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p3, k4 - k3}, {p2 - p3, k2 - k3}] == Pi/2;
```

Comment: You have 9 equations, and 8 variables.

Comment: You only need three equations concerning the vertex angles. If three of them are right angles, the fourth must be a right angle.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok, I tried 8 equation, (three equations concerning the vertex angles) but there is no [answer](http://imgur.com/9GfIcNy)..

Comment: These problems and solutions are highly constrained.  The conjecture holds for an *arbitrary* closed non-self-intersecting curve.  How would you find the point here?  `PolarPlot[Cos[t] + .3 Sin[3 t] + .1 Cos[7 t - .4] + .3 Cos[9 t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`  And how would one find *all* the inscribed squares?

Answer (score 3):

For square ABCD, given $A(x_1, y_1)$, $B(x_2, y_2)$, $C$ and $D$ are easy to get, so we can reduce the number of unknowns to 4
[image]

```
Clear["`*"];
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3;
pts = NestList[RotationMatrix[π/2].(# - {x1, y1}) + {x2, y2} &, {x1, y1}, 3]
eqn = f @@@ pts
sol = FindRoot[eqn, Transpose[{{x1, y1, x2, y2}, {0, 1, -1, 0}}]]
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -1.4, 1.4}, {y, -1.3, 1.5},
 Epilog -> ({PointSize[Large], Point[pts], Line[pts[[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}]]]} /. sol)]
```

> [image]
> You can also use NMinimize to solve the equation, no initial value is required

```
nm=NMinimize[Join[{Total[eqn^2],1/2<x1-x2<2},Thread[eqn==0]],{x1,y1,x2,y2},WorkingPrecision->50]/.x_Real:>Round[x,10^-15.]
```

> {0., {x1 -> 1., y1 -> 0., x2 -> 0., y2 -> 1.}}

Answer (score 2):

Well done [@yarchik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9469/yarchik).

But `Solve` can show the solution in `Reals` with an extra option:

```
Solve[(r^2 - 1)^3 == r^5 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3, r, Reals]
```

(*{
{r -> Root[-1 + 3 #1^2 - 3 #1^4 -
Cos[[Phi]]^2 Sin[[Phi]]^3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1]},
{r ->
Root[-1 + 3 #1^2 - 3 #1^4 -
Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2]}}*)

and even further

```
Solve[(r^2 - 1)^3 == r^5 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3 && 
  0 < ϕ < 2 π, r, Reals]
```

---

```
{{r -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-1 + 3 #1^2 - 3 #1^4 - 
       Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 1], 
    0 < ϕ < π/2 || π/
      2 < ϕ < π || π < ϕ < (3 \[Pi])/2 || (3 π)/
      2 < ϕ < 2 π]}, 

{r -> 
       ConditionalExpression[
        Root[-1 + 3 #1^2 - 3 #1^4 - 
           Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3 #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2], 
        0 < ϕ < π/2 || π/
          2 < ϕ < π || π < ϕ < (3 π)/2 || (3 π)/
          2 < ϕ < 2 π]}}
```

Powerful `Solve` is not it.

Compared to the solution already given this is just a formal step ahead. But both real solutions to Solve form the heart curve in polar coordinates lead to the same inscribed square.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is difficult to solve in Cartesian coordinates. But it simplifies a lot in polar coordinates. Let us first convert the given implicit equation into this form. We substitute $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$  and obtain

$$(r^2-1)^3=r^5 \cos^2\phi \sin^3\phi.$$

This is an algebraic equation for $r$.

```
Solve[(r^2-1)^3==r^5 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3,r]
```

Upon inspection we find the positive real root is number 2. Now define the function in polar coordinates:

```
rH[ϕ_]:=Abs[Root[-1+3#1^2-3  #1^4-Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^3 #1^5+#1^6&,2]]
xy[ϕ_]:=rH[ϕ]{Cos[ϕ],Sin[ϕ]}
```

Only 4 equations need to be solved:

```
eq1=EuclideanDistance[xy[t1],xy[t2]]==EuclideanDistance[xy[t2],xy[t3]]==EuclideanDistance[xy[t4],xy[t1]];
eq2=VectorAngle[xy[t1]-xy[t2],xy[t2]-xy[t3]]==Pi/2;
eq3=VectorAngle[xy[t4]-xy[t1],xy[t1]-xy[t2]]==Pi/2;
```

Let us invent some initial guess for `FindRoot`

```
δ=0.2;
```

and do the calculations

```
res=FindRoot[{eq1,eq2,eq3},{{t1,0+δ},{t2,π/2+δ},{t3,π+δ},{t4,3π/2+δ}},AccuracyGoal->5];

pts=xy[N[#]]&/@({t1,t2,t3,t4,t1}/.res);

PolarPlot[rH[ϕ],{ϕ,0,2π},PlotRange->All,Axes->False,Epilog->{PointSize->Large,Point[#]&/@pts,Line[pts]}]
```

[image]

It is easy to verify that $\phi_i=\pi/2(i-1)$ is an exact solution.